# Can there be an interference term in a two-state quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Say I have a two-state system $|\psi \rangle=c_1|0\rangle+c_2|1\rangle$. If the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are orthogonal, then the probability is:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi |\psi \rangle&=(\langle 0|c_1^* + \langle 1|c_2^* )(c_1|0\rangle+c_2|1\rangle)\\
&=c_1^*c_1\langle 0|0\rangle+c_2c_2^*\langle 1|1\rangle + c_1^*c_2\langle 0|1\rangle+c_1c_2^*\langle 1|0\rangle\\
&=c_1^*c_1+c_2c_2^*=1
\end{align}
$$

Unlike the double split experiment, there are no interference terms:

$$
P=|\psi_1|^2+|\psi_2|^2+2|\psi_1||\psi_2|\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)
$$

Can a two-state system produce a similar $\cos$-based interference term?

Comment: Look at what happens if you calculate $\langle \psi | \varphi\rangle$ where the 2 states are not the same

Comment: @BySymmetry So $|\psi \rangle=c_1|0\rangle+c_2|1\rangle$ and $\phi\rangle=a_1 |0\rangle+a_2 |1\rangle$. Then $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = c_1^*a_1 +  c_2^*a_2$. That is equal to $1$, right? Where is the cos interference term?

Comment: Not is it not $=1$ in general.  Take $c_1=1/\sqrt{3}, c_2=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ but $a_1=a_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @BySymmetry Is this what you have in mind: $|\psi \rangle =c_1|0\rangle +c_2|1\rangle$ and $|\rangle =_1|0\rangle+_2|1\rangle$? If so, then $\langle |\rangle=_1^*_1+_2^*_2$, which contains no interference terms.

Comment: Your previous statement $\uparrow$ is incorrect, as demonstrated by a full calculation.  In fact this is in general a complex number.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, but the structure of the probability is a sum of both events $|\psi_1|^2$ and $|\psi_2|^2$ followed by another interference term $2|\psi_1||\psi_2|\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$. Your proposal produces only 1 complex number $e^{-i\gamma}\sin \beta$ and thus is not the same as the probability distribution $P$.

Comment: add the complex conjugate from the second cross term and you have an interference term in $\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Take
\begin{align}
\vert\psi_1\rangle&=e^{-\frac{i \gamma }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)
\vert 0\rangle+ e^{-\frac{i \gamma }{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)\vert 1\rangle\, ,\\
\vert\psi_2\rangle&=
e^{\frac{i \gamma }{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)\vert 0\rangle + e^{\frac{i \gamma }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)\vert 1\rangle
\end{align}
for which $\langle \psi_1\vert \psi_2\rangle=e^{-i\gamma}\sin\beta$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\langle 1 | 0 \rangle$ is not orthogonal?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay no I cannot as this was a typesetting error on my part.  I just corrected it.

Comment: So the key is to use 2 parameters $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in both wavefunctions , instead of 4 unique parameters?

Comment: there are still 4 coefficients. you could write $c_1$ etc as you did before.  Your error is in assuming things like $c_1^*a_1+ c_2^* a_2=1$, which is not true in general.  If you want take the angle $\beta$ in $\vert \psi_2\rangle$ to be different from the one in $\vert\psi_1\rangle$ to get an even more general overlap.

Comment: I think I might have it, but it appears that the interference term of P is the interference of a mixture, not a pure state. If I have $|\psi_1 \rangle = z_1 e^{i\theta_1} | 0\rangle$ and $|\psi_2 \rangle = z_2 e^{i\theta_2} |0\rangle$, then $\langle \psi_1+\psi_2 | \psi_1+\psi_2 \rangle=|z_1|^2+ |z_2|^2 + 2 |z_1||z_2|\cos (\theta_2-\theta_1)$

Comment: the states given above in my answer are represented by kets and thus pure, not mixed states.  Moreover in your example you work with unnormalized kets...you should have $\vert z_1\vert=\vert z_2\vert=1$.